# Checkout process not proceeding after 2 step in magento 1.9.4

Tags: customer, onepage-checkout, magento-1.9.4

The **customer** get **stuck** in **step2** of checkout proces (`onepage-checkout`).

All fields are filled in step 2 but `no response` using the `next button`.
What can causing this issue?

Comment: disable other shipping methods like usps, dhl fedex and etc. try to enable freeshipping and flat rate only then check if it works

Comment: Thanks, this solution does not help.
I disabled recaptcha. This helps, but is not a status I want.